# Ruby on Rails: How to assign a hard value to a variable?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, routes, variable-assignment

I am using multiple redirects, and I would like to redirect from A->B->C->A.

So in B, I save path A as

```
@previouspage = request.referer
```

and so @previouspage = A at this point, but when I call @previouspage in C, it doesn't bring the hard value saved in B, but finds its own relative request.referer, which is B.

So in C, @previouspage = B (because I think variables in Ruby are soft-links)

How would I just save whatever the value of request.referer was at point B, and then save that URL into a variable that I can access later?

Comment: don't you think it's better to save your values on your session instead?

Comment: @VincentPaca saving it in sessions didnt prevent the stored value from changing.. :( see my gist below

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is a stateless protocol: variables are not remembered between requests. If you want to save state between requests, then you might use a session. In Rails it is done like this:

In B:

```
session[:page_a] = request.referer
```

In C:

```
@next_page = session[:page_a]
```

The [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) begins with sessions and their vulnerabilities. You might want to check it out.

Comment: I tried this, but the "@next_page" still tries to find it's own request.referer, which happens to be B. I used puts to see what the values of the variables were, and in B, the session[:page_a] stores what I need(A), but @next_page changes values to B, not A.

Comment: here is the gist and logs that shows that session[:page_a] changes after user logs in. https://gist.github.com/3076131

Comment: my guess is that you are also assigning `session[:page_a]` in C

Answer (score 2):

Rails variables are not kept between requests. If you want to save some data, you should:

- Save it in a (session) cookie
- Save it in the database
- Pull some tricks out of your sleeve and pass the referer as a parameter or something like that but it is not recommended at all.

Answer (score 2):

Three things needed to get this working

- Using sessions: sessions[:original_page]=request.referrer
- Accounting for the fact that sessions get refreshed after login (check if nil)
- Remembering to set session[:original_page]=nil right after using it in the controller.

Comment: btw, do you have your full code on github?  will probably be easier to run it myself.  my head is spinning trying to do this on paper!

Comment: The full code is in a private repo; is it too hard to do it without the entire code?

Comment: Oh no worries.  I was having difficulty figuring out which actions are being hit by the store_location before filter.    what are all the actions under missions controller?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3077397 Here is the full file for the missions_controller :). I think you may be right in that it refreshes the session because I am basically telling the after_sign_in_path to go to an action, which would call the before_filter :store_location.

Comment: Are you using the 'store_location' before filter outside MissionsController?  BTW, have you considered asking users to 'login to vote' instead?  Don't mean to interfere on your design decisions!  just curious.  Even if it is not the before_filter, am not sure you can keep the path from before the user logged in in your session

Comment: What do you mean by whether I'm using the 'store_location' filter outside MissionsController? I guess I'm defining it in the ApplicationController, and applying the filter on other controllers (including MissionsController). Could you also clarify what you mean by asking users to 'login to vote?' I am currently using the before_filter :authenticate_user! to force users to login before they can access other actions. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: 1. If the store_location is being called before the "user sign in" page for example, wouldn't that change the session value too?  2. 'login to vote' meaning you will redirect to page A after the user logged in.  they can then click on the Vote button.   if you use Ajax there is no additional page refresh.   But that is a design change.  Just wondering if you had considered it.   3. I updated my answer with a possible solution. I'd be curious if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, so instead of defining a new method called "stored_location," would it be smarter to save the session in the sign_in action? (tho I'm not sure where that would be in Devise) That way the session is only stored once, when the user is trying to log in? // Yes, I would like to eventually Ajaxify a lot of the actions, but I am still a newbie and don't know much Ajax/JS. One thing at a time, Rails being my current struggle ;)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding, but I am not sure I understand what you mean by "seperate the two." Am I not already storing the original page in A and the vote action separately with "session[:page_a] = request.referer
    session[:current_path] = "http://localhost:3000" + request.fullpath" in the store location? The values are saved correctly initially, but the problem is that it gets overwritten when the before_filter is called again.

Comment: I see the confusion.  I am saying try storing just the 'vote' action in store_location.  The page A will be stored in :backto outside store_location.  this way it won't be over written.   btw, i don't mean to be nosy about your private code but this issue probably needs to be looked at as a whole.  so if you can share the application controller & user controller, that will be awesome.

Comment: i just updated the answer with code snippets.  hope that solves some of the confusion.  i think this will do the trick.

Comment: This didn't work. I don't think it's a matter of limiting the before_filter on actions, as I've only been testing with the votes anyways. I think we need to limit it to the conditions when the user is logged in, and isn't logged in. For example, when I use "if !user_signed_in? then store session_a," it works perfectly, as the sessions don't get overwritten after the user is logged in. However, this doesn't work when the User is logged in, and to assign a session in the "else" condition would mean that would override the session once the user is authenticated. (explaining it here is confusing)

Comment: I GOT IT TO FINALLY WORK! I USED THE || OPERATOR TO REDIRECT TO THE SESSION ONLY IF IT EXISTED. SEE: https://gist.github.com/3079018

Comment: congrats! That is exactly what I was going to test if I got to see the whole code. You should probably add your own answer for others to see!

Comment: thanks:) actually, the solution isn't complete, because I can access the "vote" button from 2 pages (index,show), and once the user logs in, I need the session to delete, so it only goes to "request.referer." Otherwise, it redirects only to the url that the session initially stored, when I would like it to redirect to referer now that user is signed in.I am currently looking at ways to get rid of the session[:original_page] once the user is redirected to it once. I guess I could potentially just make that session expire in 10seconds or something, but that would be a hackish way I'm assuming...

Comment: Does setting session[:original_page]=nil right after you use it work? In the worst case, you can pass the 'next_page' as params.

Comment: Awesome!  I enjoyed troubleshooting this.   I updated my Answer with the gist of what we did to get it to work.  feel free to edit it with your actual code snippets